# How to remove Partitions in windows 10 boot?

Tags: windows, boot, repair

I think my windows 10 startup is all messed. Always, when it boots, it makes me choose between FIVE "installations" / drives. "On partition X" "On device X"... I would like to clear all of it and leave only the one that do exists, which is my current installed Windows 10 64 bits. Is there a program which would allow me to mess with this stuff? Or a simple command line? I dont have the recovery disks or windows 10 setup disk, it came pre-installed, it's and HP.

Comment: You will need a Windows 10 1607 ISO to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use EasyBCD (https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) to fix your Boot settings.
Just make sure to not delete the correct entry. When you are left with only one entry you can also set the 30s wait-time to 0s so you wont be bothered anymore with a menu.